# Mongoose not pushing to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schema:

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    likes: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0,
    },
    reactedBy: [
        {
            required: true,
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
            default: []
        },
    ],
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: () => Date.now(),
    },
    updatedAt: Date,
});

export default mongoose.models.Review || mongoose.model("Review", ReviewSchema);**
```

I'm using this function to add to `reactedBy`:

```js
await Review.updateOne ({_id: parsedRequest.id}, {likes: newLikeTotal}, { $push: {reactedBy: user._id}})
```

I'm getting no errors but it's not initializing or pushing to the array. Mongoose says it's been acknowledged. What's wrong here?

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question. You appear to be passing too many arguments to `updateOne()`. Perhaps you should consult [the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.updateOne())

Answer (score 0):

You should add `$push` in the second argument of the `update` function. Try this:

```
await Review.updateOne(
  {
    _id: parsedRequest.id
  }, 
  {
    likes: newLikeTotal,
    $push: {
      reactedBy: user._id
    }
  }
)
```